# How to stop AlarmManager when activity start

Tags: android, notifications

I'm a newbie in android. Today I tried working with AlarmManage for my Reminder application that allow users can input hour and minutes to show notification and I have some problem with it. 
 1. The first problem is when the notification appear, it just vibrate and didn't have sound although I have set sound default for notification and setting allow sound for my phone. 
 2. when I close the application, if i touch at notification, the MainActivity will be show and AlarmManager working again that make my application show notification again. But if i touch at notification when the application opened, The notification won't show. so I want my application just notification once time. How I can do it ?.
 3. Although I set time for reminding, but when i closed application, sometime my phone appear notification of my remind application at time i have never set. How can i fix this problem ?

MyAlarmService

```
private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
   // Toast.makeText(this, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    long[] v = {500,1000};
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setVibrate(v)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_remind)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("This is a test message!");
    mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);



    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
    mManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
```

MainActivity

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText edt_hours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_hour);
    final EditText edt_minutes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_minutes);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(edt_hours.getText().toString()));
             calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(edt_minutes.getText().toString()));
            //calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

            alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
    });



} //end onCre
```

p/s: I'm so sorry if my question is not clearly because my english is not good. And I want to say thanks you for anyone who read this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my sample code. I think It will help you.

MainActivity

```
 public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101; 

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

To Cancel Notification:

```
public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Define sound URI
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EmptyActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        int color = 0xffffaa00;
//        int color1 = context.getColor(R.color.notificatinBackgroundColor);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.festi_push_message_small);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification Sample");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentText(message + ", Current Time : " + dateTime.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime.getSecondOfMinute());
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
        builder.setColor(color);


        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
```

Comment: thanks you bro, it works perfectly. But i dont know why my code didn't work. And in your code, the sound is still not working

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Use this "  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);" insteadof "Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);" in MainActivity. And now try again

Comment: I use your code but the sound still not working :(. I think this problem is my phone :(. Bcuz i try install some app the same in CHplay. ANd the sound not woriking. thanks you for answer :)