# Alarmmanager not cancel after clicking notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am developing an app with alarmmanager and services and I cannot cancel the notification in certain cases. I am using fragments.

My app send two notifications every "x" different minutes. I have a button to start the service and another one to stop it. When I start the service the notifications are fired and when I press the stop button it works correctly. But when I start the service and I exit the app, the notifications are fired normally but when I click a notification, the app is opened and then I press the stop button but the notifications never stop, the notifications continue being fired.

The function where I call alarmanager.cancel(pendingintent) is in the same fragment.. (MainFragment.class which is the first fragment).

MainFragment.class

```
    intent = new Intent(getContext(), TimeAlarm.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 15000,
                15000,
                pendingIntent);

    intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), TimeAlarm2.class);
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
    intent2.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1,
            intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 15000,
                        15000,
                        pendingIntent2);
```

TimeAlarm.class which extends BroadcastReceiver

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("...")
                .setContentText("...");

 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

TimeAlarm2.class which extends BroadcastReceiver

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2)
                .setContentTitle("..")
                .setContentText("..");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder2.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        mBuilder2.setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder2.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder2.build());
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: This may help you to fix this, but I am not sure. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347187/how-to-stop-alarmmanager-when-activity-start/36349036#36349036

Comment: @Sabari Thanks, I solved it by mixing code. But now, the problem is when I kill the app manually.. The notifications are continue fired and when I open the app again and I press the stop button the alarm manager is not cancelled.

Comment: Could you share the stop button click event fully?

Comment: @Sabari In the cancelAlarm() function I just have  am.cancel(pendingIntent);
am.cancel(pendingIntent2);
And the pendingIntent's are global and defined in the onCreate method..

Comment: Your code is little confusing to me. Are you calling this "am.setRepeating"  and initiallizing "pendingIntent "  inside "start" click event?

Comment: @Sabari Nop, I am initiallizing "pendingIntent" inside onCreate, and I have a function "startAlarm()" with the am.setRepeating and another function "cancelAlarm()" with the am.cancel..
Both functions outside onCreate

Comment: Remove these lines from both intent and try it. "intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
  intent2.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));". It is working for me

Comment: @Sabari Well, now everything is working at all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always welcome and I have posted this as answer, please close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from both intent and try it again.

```
intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
intent2.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

It is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this and if the error comes telling me what happens.

For that you need to destroy the service on the stop button and again start service on start button click.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I can suggest you to call `cancel()` on **AlarmManager** with an equivalent PendingIntent to the one you used with `setRepeating()` method.

Here you can cancel both of your equivalent pendingIntent.

```
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

and

```
am.cancel(pendingIntent2);
```

Hope it will help you.