# Stop Sending Local Notification android

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on the Local Notification on Android. The notification is sent  based on a given time.

The user can control this notification using a Switch (if it is ON -> Notification will be sent, and if it is OFF -> this notification has to be deleted "NOt Only Cancelled" and not be sent at all). The ON case works perfect, but for the OFF case, the notification is still be sent.

Can anyone help on "Stop" sending the notification when Switch is set to OFF?

Here is the Switch I am using:
[image]

And this is the code I am using:

```
if(isChecked == true)
    {
        // Send the Notification

} else {

        // Stop Sending the Notification 

    }
```

Comment: Can you give more information, for example, on where you have your code and what you already tried?

Comment: This may help you, but I am not sure. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347187/how-to-stop-alarmmanager-when-activity-start/36349036#36349036

Comment: @Sabari Thank you so much. This is exactly what I am looking for. Can you add that as an answer to this question ?

Comment: That's is fine, I have posted this as answer. Please close this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, but I am not sure.

Ref:[How to stop AlarmManager when activity start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347187/how-to-stop-alarmmanager-when-activity-start/36349036#36349036)

To Cancel Notification:

```
public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```